# Why is Xsara Picasso referred as N68?

Tags: citroen

I'm trying to understand my car better and one thing I see commonly is that it is referred as "Xsara Picasso (N68)". Is it the name of the engine?

Can you provide reference so I can read where this code comes from? I can't find anything

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a vehicle is referred to like this, **it usually has to do with the model generation of the vehicle in question**. For instance, most BMW fans will refer to a 5th generation 3 Series sedan, which was produced between 2004 to 2010 as an ***E90***. It could be considered easier to refer to these vehicles this way since it encompasses the entire year range this generation was built. E90 is what BMW called it internally and is what was picked up on the street for an easy description. It is much easier for a manufacturer to state "N68" rather than spelling out the entire thing of "Citroën Xsara Picasso manufactured from 1999-2012". Both give the same information (if you know what it means), just the one is a LOT shorter.

**NOTE:** I can't find much on this either to provide you a link. I've only figured this out over time as I've had to decipher what the heck others were talking about. I did a Google search on exactly what you put in and it appears my suspicions are correct about the designator you provided.

Comment: Thanks Paul, cheers